Setting up my own smtp server and send unauthenticated messages
I’m having a hard time getting to the point.
Let’s assume I have my own domain (ABC.com), and I’ve set up my own SMTP server (Stalwart Email Server).
After configuring the SMTP server, I added the necessary DNS records. Let’s also assume that authentication is not required on the SMTP server, meaning anyone can send an email (so the 'from' field can be anything).
On the other side, I have a simple Node.js app using Nodemailer to initiate the transport and send the email (mail.abc.com:25).
I’m not receiving any errors, but when I try sending the email to a Gmail account, it’s not appearing. Am I missing something? If so, could you clarify it for me?
**Just want to clarify that stalwart generates the relevant records including dmarc, spf etc.
